# Java to C# - CallableStatement convert

Tags: c#, java, .net, cubrid

Hi I am trying to understand how to convert java code to C#, I read some tutorials about java but I dont find the way in how to translate this lines of code:

```java
CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("?=CALL
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.JAVA_OBJECT);
cstmt.execute(); 
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) cstmt.getObject(1);
```

I try with

```cpp
  CUBRIDConnection con = new CUBRIDConnection(ConnectionString);
  CUBRIDCommand com = new CUBRIDCommand();
  com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  com.Connection = con;
  com.CommandText = "call mySP();";
  com.Parameters.Add("?=p", CUBRIDDataType.CCI_U_TYPE_RESULTSET).Direction =
      ParameterDirection.Output;
  con.Open();
  DbDataReader df = com.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult);
  //some stuff
  con.Close();
```

This dont work, how can I translate it?

Comment: You might translate an *algorithm* coded in Java to one coded in C#.  Translating modest size programs is really, really hard because the of huge differences in the Java and C# underlying libraries that applications must use.

Comment: is your Java Application pointing to SQL Server or Oracle database?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza: to [CUBRID](http://www.cubrid.org/) database: "**CUBRIDConnection**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("your connection string");
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    com.Connection = con;
    com.CommandText = "yourstoredprocedurename"; //no paranthesis or call key word just procedure name
    SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("yourparametername", SqlDbType.Binary); //just parameter name no questionmark
    parameter.Direction= ParameterDirection.Output;
    com.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    con.Open();
    var df = com.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult);
    //some stuff
    con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have outlined the following lines which could be improved to help it work:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("ValidConnectionString");    

com.CommandText = "storedProcedureName"; // You need to give the command the actual SP name, call mySP(); is invalid.

com.Parameters.Add("@ParameterName", SqlDbType.Binary).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; // Parameters are usually prefixed with @ParameterName (some people omit the @) however this is preference amongst developers.
```

Note: You will have to replace "ValidConnectionString" with your connectionString (unless ConnectionString is the variable holding this information). Incase it is not, a connection string looks like:  `Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;`  which would connect to a SQL Server 2008 database.  For other connection strings, look at the following site:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 0):

I solve it using the following.

http://www.cubrid.org/?mid=forum&category=195532&document_srl=358924